# Replacing table values with txt file VFP

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro, dbase, xbase

im  trying to replace a phc table with information from a txtfile but im not getting the information on the screen.

re is the table i want to replace the values
txtcabecalho is the imported file that people have to choose
reciboc is the cursor that i've created to store the values from the txt file so i can replace them on re and show them to the screen
sre is the screen of the table re.

```
    Local txtcabecalho
Use re
Delete all
txtcabecalho=getfile("txt")

Create cursor reciboc(rno n(10), rdata d(10), moeda c(3), no n(10), nome c(2), ccusto c(20), intid c(10), clbanco c(20), total float(19), totalmoeda float(19), ndoc n(3))


append from (txtcabecalho) delimited with tab
select reciboc
goto top
scan for !empty(reciboc.rno)

select re
append blank
replace re.rno with reciboc.rno 
replace re.rdata with reciboc.rdata
replace re.moeda with reciboc.moeda
replace re.no with reciboc.no
replace re.nome with reciboc.nome
replace re.ccusto with reciboc.ccusto
replace re.intid with reciboc.intid
replace re.clbanco with reciboc.clbanco
replace re.total with reciboc.total 
replace re.totalmoeda with reciboc.totalmoeda 
replace re.ndoc with reciboc.ndoc
select re
endscan

sre.refresh()
```

Thanks!

Updated

So this actually works if i crate a file of my own with the delimitianion i choose for example with tabs. Thi thing is the files that i need to import are like using spaces as spaceholders and got no delimitations from each other. Let me explain better. for example first 3 fields rno and rdata and moeda.

The txt files come like `22014-12-23EUR`

Where **2 is the rno** but has 9 spaces behind working like place holders for bigger numbers making the rno(10)
Next is 2014-12-23 wich is right next to the rno with no delimitation wich does the rdata(10) 
Next is the moeda wich is EUR , again with no delimitation , being the moeda(3)

Many fields will be blank , and those the txt files come with spaces ocupying full length of the fields. Basically, field length is used as delimitation, and when empty , its filled with spaces.

Did u understood right? sorry im not an english native.

update

heres is some of the txt file `22014-11-27EUR       208                                                                                                         799,00             799,00  00`

just keep in mind that before the first number 2 , there are 9 spaces.
Thanks!

the rdata field wich is going to be filled with 2014-11-27 is rdata d(10)

**edited**

currently code:

```
Local txtcabecalho, fileconvert
Use re
zap
txtcabecalho=getfile("txt")
Create cursor reciboc(rno n(10), rdata d(10), moeda c(3), no n(10), nome c(2), ccusto c(20), intid c(10), gg c(20), chq c(20), clbanco c(20), total float(19), totalmoeda float(19), ndoc n(3))

fileconvert = filetostr(txtcabecalho)
chrtran(fileconvert,'-','')
strtofile(fileconvert, txtcabecalho)

append from (txtcabecalho) type sdf
scan 
select re
append blank
replace rno with reciboc.rno 
replace rdata with reciboc.rdata
replace moeda with reciboc.moeda
replace no with reciboc.no
replace nome with reciboc.nome
replace ccusto with reciboc.ccusto
replace intid with reciboc.intid
replace clbanco with reciboc.clbanco
replace total with reciboc.total 
replace totalmoeda with reciboc.totalmoeda 
replace ndoc with reciboc.ndoc
select re

endscan
select reciboc
browse title "resultado"

reindex
sre.refresh()
```

what i get is [this is what i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGIy0.png)

stil ltrying to figure out i really don't know aff

for example : firt row should be:

RNO 2
RDATA 2014-11-27
NO 208

**EDITED**

actually this made it ahah

```
fileconvert = filetostr(txtcabecalho)
fileconvert2 = strtran(fileconvert,'-','')
strtofile(fileconvert2, txtcabecalho)
```

if i need further help i'll update my question! Thank you so much guys!

**EDITED**

Doyou guys know if there is any problem converting from txt file float numbers to cursors?

I got for example 799,20 but i just show up as 799. Data type is set to totalmoeda f(19) . This must be pretty simple but i can't find it!

Comment: Just as a side note, when you need to issue multiple replace commands, do not issue separate replace commands but a single one. You can do many replacements with a single one like so: replace f1 with 'f1content', f2 with 'f2Content' ... That does the replacement with a single pass. Yours do a replacement pass per replace. Not important here, but keep that in mind, greatly affects performance (and VFP developers are performance crazy).

Comment: Type float is the same as type numeric. If you want decimals, you have to include them in the column's definition. F(19) is an integer, despite the data type.

Comment: I tried to figure out to do it but i can't understand how im suposed to do that

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a SCAN loop which implies many rows from the reciboc table.  However, in your "re" table, you just keep overwriting the same row with the same values, and if no record on file, you will have nothing anyhow.  If you want to add them, you need to append to the "RE" table.

Now, another consideration is the "rno" column.  Is that supposed to be an "ID" column such as your external text file may have updated values for each given "RNO" and you want to update if it does not exist yet, or add if it does NOT exist in the "re" table?

UPDATE for your question with tags and extra clarified elements...

If you have an index on you "RE" table on the "RNO" column, great.  If not, and that is the key column that you want to update based on, I suggest creating an index on it...

From the VFP command window, build the index so it is always available

```
use RE exclusive
index on RNO tag RNO
use
```

Now, in your code, AFTER Your Append from delimited, and your cursor is prepared...  I would set a relationship between the live table and your temp cursor and do the update like...

select reciboc
index on RNO tag RNO   && so the cursor has an index too.

selece RE
set relation to RNO into RECIBOC

Now, the two tables are pointing to each other for whatever records match in each table.  Now, replace FOR [scope].  Due to the relationship, as the records are cycled in the "RE" table, it will point to the same RNO record in the "RECIBOC" table if one exists.  So the FOR condition is testing for NOT EOF() (end of file = no match found in RECIBOC.  So NOT EOF() means there IS a record found.

```
replace rdata with reciboc.rdata,;
        moeda with reciboc.moeda,;
        no with reciboc.no,;
        nome with reciboc.nome,;
        ccusto with reciboc.ccusto,;
        intid with reciboc.intid,;
        clbanco with reciboc.clbanco,;
        total with reciboc.total,;
        totalmoeda with reciboc.totalmoeda,;
        ndoc with reciboc.ndoc ;
   FOR NOT EOF( "RECIBOC" )
```

finally, get any NEW "RNO" records into your "RE" table.  Get all records NOT in your existing RE table based on matching "RNO" column.

```
select * ;
   from RECIBOC ;
   WHERE RNO NOT IN ( select RNO from RE );
   into cursor NewRecordsToAdd readwrite
```

Now, add them to the "RE" table.  Since the columns are the same name, they will come over directly without explicit column name from/to reference.

```
select RE
append from dbf( "NewRecordsToAd" )
use in select( "NewRecordsToAdd" )
```

Comment: @joh, just revised answer.  Also, for future, you can edit your original question instead of posting answer to it.  You can add comments to a person's post so they see that you responded.  Also take a look at top menu "Help -> Tour" for site etiquette too.

Comment: thanks for all your help but im a very basic vfp programer and i kind of didnt get half of the information u got there. i'm using like a mix of VFP , xBase and Clipper i think , im using it to customize some PHC actions , PHC is an ERP. I think i couldn't make you sure about what i was tryng to do. Basicaly i want to browse for an txt file , and replace the in screen fields with the information that the txt file has. the synthax is not exactly the same as raw VFP but i can get the idea. my main problem is to put the TXT FILE DATA RESPECTIVELY into the CURSOR fields. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Create Cursor reciboc(rno N(10), rdata d(10), moeda c(3), no N(10), ;
    Nome c(2), ccusto c(20), intid c(10), clbanco c(20), ;
    Total Float(19), totalmoeda Float(19), ndoc N(3))

Append From (m.txtcabecalho) Type Delimited With Blank

Select re
Append from (Dbf('reciboc'))
```

Above is the shorter version for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

In your update what you are describing is a Fixed Width Data format or what is known as System Data Format (SDF). Then do not use delimited but SDF as the type:

```
Create Cursor reciboc(rno C(10), rdata C(10), moeda c(3), no C(10), ;
    Nome c(2), ccusto c(20), intid c(10), clbanco c(20), ;
    Total C(19), totalmoeda C(19), ndoc C(3))

Append From (m.txtcabecalho) Type SDF

alter table reciboc alter column rdata d && convert rdata column to date
* do other needed column type conversions

Select re
Append from (Dbf('reciboc'))
```

The sizes you use when creating your cursor should match with the sizes of data columns in your text file. After getting the whole data as text, alter columns to match the data types (I assumed your sizes were right) - d(10) was meaningless, and float is never a suggested type.

PS: If you can find FoxyClasses then it does have an importer class in it which handles much of the work for you (unfortunately I lost the server where I was serving the download). You can read the details in its chm file if you can find.

Comment: Man thank you SO MUCH , as i said im like 2 days into this languages and i got still many to learn. one thing. The format that the re table is formated for is dd-mm-yyyy but the file comes formated with yyyy-mm-dd , do you guys know how to counter this? If i dont change this everything gets messes ahah . its the rdata field from both

Comment: Whatever the format in the text file, then set your date format to match. ie: If in text file it is yyyy-mm-dd then: "set date YMD" if it is dd-mm-yyyy then "set date DMY". Issue this command anywhere before doing the alter table stuff. And also, say if the date format was something that is not standard, then you could manipulate the data using a function too (but that is advanced for you now).

Comment: i think there is some conflit with the - - - i got the same problem. Following the examples i gave instead of showing EUR is showin 28E where 28 is part of the date and on the date shows nothing. so i feel like there is a problem with 3 chars , probbly the - - - . Ill keep working on it to see ifi can get a solution. thank you !

Comment: Why don't you give us a few lines from your text file? (it would be nice if you can edit your question and add lines as is there).

Comment: i dont think that stackoverflow detects spaces. but here it is:

         22014-11-27EUR       208                                                                                                         799,00             799,00  00

the date is confliting , because on where was suposed to show EUR , is showing 27E.

Comment: Here, in comments you are right I wouldn't be able to get that as is. However you can edit your original question and add there as "code".

Answer (score 0):

With exactly 9 spaces before 2 it works for me:

```
Create Cursor reciboc(rno C(10), rdata C(10), moeda c(3), no C(10), ;
    Nome c(2), ccusto c(20), intid c(10), clbanco c(20), ;
    Total C(19), totalmoeda C(19), ndoc C(3))

Append From (m.txtcabecalho) Type SDF
browse title "Before data type change"

Set Date YMD
Set Century ON

alter table reciboc alter column rdata d && convert rdata column to date
browse title "After date type change"
```

In case of SDF, keep in mind positions in text file specify field widths.

Comment: i'm still having the same problem and i can't figure it out. The rdata field in my cursor has 10 width. BUT if i take out the "-" "-" of the text file everything works just fine , even if it after stays with 8 width. changing re table or text files is not an option. I'm assuming that there are already  two "-"  on the rdata field in the table re that are filling 2 spaces , leaving just 8 thats why it fits right. What do you think? I don't know how do i put the data into the rdata making it to ignore the "-" from the txt file. 

Thanks for your help guys

Comment: There is chrtran() and strtran() functions but I don't understand what you mean. Try, replace rdata with chrtran(rdata,'-','') all - on reciboc before alter table command. It simply works with - for me.

Comment: Check set point. Or alternatively you can replace comma with th proper decimal separator dot.